# Declarative services component both satisfied and unsatisfied

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, declarative-services

I am developing an OSGI-based system which uses declarative services to define components. However, when running it from Eclipse, one of my components is not initialized. When I investigate the issue using simple console commands, I get the following output (with some small obfuscation):

```
osgi> component 51
    Component[
    name = com.e.location.view
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = com.e.location.view.LocationViewContribution
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [com.e.model.ViewContribution]
    references = {
        Reference[name = SpecificationProvider, interface = com.e.SpecificationProvider, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setSpecificationProvider, unbind = null]
    }
    located in bundle = com.e.location.view_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT [107]
]
Dynamic information :
  The component is satisfied
  All component references are satisfied
  Component configurations :
    Configuration properties:
      component.name = com.e.location.view
      component.id = 55
      objectClass = String[com.e.model.ViewContribution]
    Instances:
```

So the component has `state = Unsatisfied`, but the dynamic information states the component is satisfied and its component references are satisfied too.

Can anybody explain this? Why is my component not initialized?

UPDATE: Apparently, setting `immedate="true"` for the component fixes the initialization problem. The osgi command still has `state = Unsatisfied` though. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

We had similar issues when:

- The activate method of the component threw an exception (see the log)
- The activate method of the component did not return (see a thread dump)

  - Infinite loop (or JVM enhanced recursion) in activate
  - Deadlock

If you are in equinox and did not install a bundle that forwards the LogEvents to the logfile/console, do not forget to check the configuration directory, where equinox puts log files for error messages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have not defined an activation method. Could this be causing the problem as well?

Comment: You do not have to have activate method. However, if the activate method is listed in the component xml, it should be available in the class. Did you check the error logs?

Comment: I checked the error logs, couldn't find anything. I updated my question though

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the constructor of your component must not have arguments.

Also, force enabling using `enabled="true" immediate="true"` attributes in the `<scr:component>` tag.

Comment: I made sure they have a constructor like that. Also, if the component doesn't have a constructor like that, you will see an exception in the logs. But I'm not getting that here

Comment: I've updated my answer with another possible solution :)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I already commented on immediate="true" in my question. Do you know why the shell command still says the component has state=uninitialized like I ask at the end of my question?

Comment: If you type the "ls" command you see your component "ENABLED", it isn't? (probably yes, as it has the autoenabled=true attribute, but maybe something is not enabling your component, and therefore, it is not being initialized).

Comment: The component is enabled. In fact, it's working fine. My question is why it the "component"-command still shows it as "state=unsatisfied".